# Android: I can't use a CursorAdapter because of concurrency concerns. What should I do instead?

Tags: android, concurrency, thread-safety, cursor, simplecursoradapter

thank you for your time.
Hopefully I can be as clear as possible, apologies in advance to the extent that I fail to do so.

**The situation:**
I am creating a multithreaded Android application that deals with a local database. For synchronization/concurrency reasons, I want a particular activity to have no dealings at all with a Cursor. Right now, however, it uses a CursorAdapter to show data from the db on the screen.

**The question:**
How can I replicate the functionality of a SimpleCursorAdapter without using a Cursor (because having an open cursor will introduce concurrency errors)?

*(Using an ArrayList of objects would work best, as I already have that lying around ready to play with.)*

Thank you. I will stick around and clarify everything as needed.

Answer (score 0):

Something that may be useful:

If you want to deal with Cursors in a threadsafe way on an asynchronous thread (i.e. predictably)  try using runOnUiThread: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#runOnUiThread(java.lang.Runnable)

The code is as follows:

```
activity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
           @Override
           public void run() {
               //Paste code here
           }
       });
```

This code would go in one of the AsyncTask overloads such as onPreExecute or doInBackground.

This may allow you to run non-thread-safe code in a more threadsafe manner.

I hope this helps!